# ".on" method from Jquery doesnt works after dynamically generated dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have a problem with dinamically generated select combobox.
how it should work:

I have one select combobox with static values written inside my code, and the next one should change
accordingly to the selected result of the previous one. The next one, should work the same way, but when a select an option inside the jquery generated select combobox, 
the jquery doesnt work anymore and therefore third one is not generated. I am using the same class for all those lists . How could i solve this?

PS: I'm using jquery version 1.9.1 and ".on" method

```
$(".select-line-pattern").on("change", function() {
    var select_line_pattern_id = $(this).attr("id");  //Returns the id of the select combobox e.g: input-line-add-line-pattern-1
        var select_line_pattern_value = $(this).val(); //Returns value of the select combobox  e.g: 1
        var combobox_line_pattern = $(this).parent("p"); Receive the pattern of the select combobox

        var id_split = select_line_pattern_id.split('-'); //Explode by '-' e.g: input-line-add-line-pattern-1
        var select_id = id_split.pop(); //Receive the last exploded element e.g: 1
        var url_ajax = "search_line_child.php";

        $.ajax({ 
            url: url_ajax,
            data: { line_pattern: select_line_pattern_value},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){

                var select_id_next = parseInt(select_id)+1; //Increment the actual id by 1. e.g: 2
                var combobox_line_pattern_id = $(combobox_line_pattern).attr("id"); eg: combobox-line-add-line-pattern-1
                $("#"+combobox_line_pattern_id+" ~ p" ).remove(); //Remove the next one, if generated
                var combobox_line_pattern_new = combobox_line_pattern_id.replace(select_id,select_id_next); eg: combobox-line-add-line-pattern-2
                var select_line_pattern_new = select_line_pattern_id.replace(select_id,select_id_next); eg: input-line-add-line-pattern-2
                var new_combobox = '';
                $("#"+combobox_line_pattern_id).after(new_combobox);
                var new_select = '';
                $('#'+combobox_line_pattern_new).append(new_select);
                $(data).each(function(index, element) {
                    var new_option = ''+element.line_name+'';
                    $('#'+select_line_pattern_new).append(new_option);
                });
            }
        });

  });
```

```
<p id="combobox-line-add-line-pattern-1" class="combobox-line-pattern">
        <select class="form-control select-line-pattern" name="line_pattern_1" id="input-line-add-line-pattern-1" size="1">
            <option value="0">::Without Line::</option>
            <option value="1">Line 1</option>
            <option value="2">Line 2</option>
            <option value="3">Line 3</option>
        </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: check the DOC, they talk about delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) syntax of on() is different from what you have used, it is

```
$(static-ancestor-element).on(event, dynamic-selector, handler)
```

So Try

```
$(document).on("change", ".select-line-pattern", function() {
    //your stuff
})
```

The format you used is same as `$(".select-line-pattern").change(handler)` which does not handle dynamically added elements